# What is the recommended method for setting global variables that are accessible in Listeners and Controllers?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, listeners

### Background

I'm building a hosted CMS with Symfony 2.5, and in one scenario we detect the correct site account based on the domain. When the user creates any records, we use a `prePersist` to automatically insert the `siteId` into the database record (so all records are associated with the correct account). But getting the `siteId` injected into a listener that is loaded as a service, is complicated.

I can't set the `siteId` in the config parameters (because it's dynamic for each site, not a set value for the whole app).

And I can't use `$container->setParameter('siteId', $siteId)` because parameters can't be modified by the time the controller executes.

And in fact there are a lot of environmental variables that I will need to access across my project, which can't easily be manually injected all the time. Soi I would like to know what others recommend as a solution, and also whether my solution is "okay".

### Current Solution

I need to store a lot of CMS environmental variables that are accessible in various controllers, services and listeners. So I've created an `env` entity, where I can store these values for later access, and defined it as a service so that it can be injected into listeners.

**Environment Entity**

```
namespace Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms;

class Env {

    private $siteId = 0;

    public function getSiteId() {
        return $this->siteId;
    }

    public function setSiteId($siteId) {
        $this->siteId = $siteId;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Define Service.yml**

```
services:
    #Define Env as a Service
    gutensite_cms.env:
        class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms\Env

    #Inject Env into a Listener
    gutensite_cms.listener.entity_persist:
        class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\EventListener\EntityPersistListener
        arguments:
            - "@gutensite_cms.env"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

**Event Listener to Add `siteId`**

```
namespace Gutensite\CmsBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms\Env;

class EntityPersistListener
{

    private $env;

    public function __construct(Env $env) {
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setTime')) $entity->setTime(time());
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setSiteId') && !$entity->getSiteId()) $entity->setSiteId($this->env->getSiteId());
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setTimeMod')) $entity->setTimeMod(time());

        // Update the Parent View timeMod
        $this->updateView($eventArgs);
    }

    public function updateView($eventArgs)
    {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $updatedEntities = $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates();

        foreach($updatedEntities AS $entity) {
            $view = false;
            if (method_exists($entity, 'getViewVersion')) {
                $view = $entity->getViewVersion()->getView();
            }
            if (method_exists($entity, 'getView')) {
                $view = $entity->getView();
            }
            if($view) {
                $view->setTimeMod(time());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The Big Question

I do not want to introduce a bad solution into my model that would break dependency injection. So where would you **store** environmental variables that you need to **access** in lots of different controllers and listeners?

Comment: You can create a service that can resolve it and inject that wherever you need it.

Comment: @user2268997 How would that differ from my example solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my app, content is separated between "Organisations". A user can belong to many of those and can switch between organisations after logging in. So all entities created by a user belong to the current organisation. To make sure I don't have to set it explicitly each time add a new Entity, I created a listener:

```
class BoundToOrganisationListener implements EventSubscriber {

    (...)

    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            Events::prePersist
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
        $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

        if (array_key_exists('organisation', $classMetadata->reflFields) && !$entity->getOrganisation()) {
        $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
        if (empty($token)) {

        } else if($organisationId = $this->getCurrentUserOrganisationId()) {
            $organisation = $em->find('...:Organisation', $organisationId);
            $entity->setOrganisation($organisation);
        }


    }
```

I keep the current organisation in the User object(I save it to database as well) so it I can get the current Organisation User is in from the security.context service .

I also check !$entity->getOrganisation() in case I want to add something to a different organisation than the one user is in(for example when I'm admin or something) by setting it manually for the new entity.

My advise for you would be to keep the siteId in session and inject the session to a service that makes sure your new objects have the proper siteId set.

To save siteId to session, you can use the same mechanism that sensio advises for setting locale

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

you can get your siteId based on the request for sure.

Comment: Thanks. I have several questions. From my understanding you should only store data in the SESSION which is uniquely different when you or I use the same website. In the admin, yes the site we are administering may be different, so that makes complete sense. But on a public website, every visitor to a domain will get the same site. So that's why I created an entity as a service that is accessible everywhere. Are there any downsides to what I did?

Comment: I assme you have a cms for many users like  XXXX.blogspot.com YYYY.blogspot.com  etc. Your statement is partially correct. session stores data important for the currrent user, not necessairlt "unique" for the user.  From the perspective of your application, each visitor is still unique because it can visit a different domain in your application. Its like with users and user groups, although many users will belong to the same group, you will still keep that info for each user in session

Comment: Yes, the CMS hosts multiple sites as unique virtual hosts, with default subdomains (DNS gets setup so they can access their site) or their own custom domains. 

In terms of the way I've done it though, does it make sense? Are there downsides to using an entity as a service versus a SESSION?